# Xero API Layout

Tags: xero-api

Does anyone know if it is possible to output reports (profit and loss) using a layout created in Xero? My client has created a custom layout in Xero itself (available via 'Layout Options' in report page - see screenshot) that groups expenses etc in a slightly different way to the standard output and I need to use this version of the data.
Thanks
Gareth

[image]

Comment: Not a feature at the moment, but you can request it here: https://xero.uservoice.com/forums/5528-xero-accounting-api

Comment: It seems it is - see below…

Comment: I stand corrected. Nice!

Comment: It might be good to have this in the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

OK - I worked it out. You need to set standardLayout to FALSE and set the desired layout to default via Xero. Just incase anyone else needs this!